# Get HTML-source as an HTML object with ability to work in it using DOM operations

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a page, say, `https://jq.profinance.ru/html/htmlquotes/site2.jsp`, which is updated every second. My aim is to `parse` values using `Selenium`.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
mylist = []

my_tables = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('table') #operation1
for tr in my_tables.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr'): #operation2
    mylist.append(tr)
```

The problem is that Python assigns a reference to object `driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('table')` to my variable `my_tables` but not value. Hence, I do not get correct data as there is some lag between operations 1 and 2.

How can I copy the webpage HTML structure and then use `Selenium` commands to walk through the structure of my document?

I tried `pickle`, `get_aatribute("InnerHTML")`, `.page_source` but they do not work properly as they copy the string object.

Comment: You can save HTML sample as a string and use either [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [lxml.html](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) to parse it

Comment: @Andersson, thanks but very inconvenient in my case. Is there a way to do it in Selenium webdriver above copied page?

Comment: You need to handle static HTML code source. Selenium is not much suitable for this purpose

Comment: @Andersson, is there any lib that has DOM syntax identical to `Selenium`? I have much code to rewrite if I use `BS4` or `lxml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found the solution:

1. Dump file into string and save locally in a `html` file
2. Open `html` file locally.
3. If you want to get back to the website, write `driver.back()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do exactly what you're trying to do with Selenium alone. Selenium "drives" a running web browser, and if the Javascript in that browser is updating the contents of the page every second or so you'll have these timing problems.

What you can do is use Selenium to drive the browser to get a snapshot of the page's HTML as a string (exactly as you describe in your last paragraph).

Then you can use a library like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the HTML string and extract the data that you need.